# SVN merge to copy of branch gave E160013 path error. Any ideas?

Tags: svn, merge, branch

We're using 1.9.0 with a reintegrate style branch that had gone through a few iterations merging from trunk to branch and reintegration to trunk. We could have copied the trunk, but then chose to copy the branch as another branch.

`svn cp -m "" ^/branches/b1 ^/branches/b2`

b1 was rev 3944 so b2 at 3945. After some further commits to the trunk and switching a working copy to the b2 branch, trying to merge the trunk to the b2 WC gave an error such as

`svn: E160013: '/repos/projectname/!svn/rvr/3944/branches/b2' path not found`

Using --force showed that SVN considered the merge reintegrate like, presumably because b1 was a reintegrate style branch.

Repeating with a copy of b1@3944 and trying to merge gave the same error as expected.

Any ideas on the reason for the error?

We copied the trunk as the new branch to move on, but one might want to copy a branch as another without bringing the trunk up to date first.
I am wondering if it's related to bug in 1.9 we found whereby a reintegrate merge can be stuck in a perpetual cycle of unnecessary property updates, i.e. after a merge to trunk and commit, a trunk to branch merge says properties need to be updated on the branch. Do that merge and commit and then a merge from branch to trunk says that properties need to be updated on the trunk, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For Intellij IDEA

In the project where you are merging to:

1. Open "Configure Branches" under Subversion Working Copies Information.
2. There should be 3 options under Branch locations: Branches, Patches, and Tags
3. Remove the one for Branches.

Now you should be able to open the Merge From dialog.

Comment: Thanks for adding a reply Aaron, however this does not answer the question in any way.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed after that the question didn't involve Intellij IDEA.  But, it was the first that i came across in my search dealing with the problem i was having.  So, i thought i would leave it in case someone else found it.  Let me know if it would be better if i delete the answer.